# How to handle ImageView click inside a row in RecyclerView?

Tags: android, gridview, android-recyclerview, cardview

When I click ImageView, it go to GridView activity with position. When I click others area inside a cardview, it go to ItemDetailActivtiy with position. How to do one line or less than coding when click.

```
    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

        TextView tv_restaurant_name, tv_restaurant_address, tv_restaurant_phone;
        ImageView imgview;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        tv_restaurant_name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_restaurant_name);
        tv_restaurant_address = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_restaurant_address);
        tv_restaurant_phone = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_restaurant_phone);
        imgview = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imgview);
        tv_restaurant_name.setOnClickListener(this);
        tv_restaurant_address.setOnClickListener(this);
        tv_restaurant_phone.setOnClickListener(this);
        imgview.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int position = getAdapterPosition();
        if (v.getId() == imgview.getId()) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, GridView.class);
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putInt("ID", Integer.valueOf(mRestaurantList.get(position).getRestaurantId()));
            intent.putExtras(bundle);
            context.startActivity(intent);
        } else {
            context.startActivity(new Intent(context, ItemDetailActivtiy.class));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to use [ButterKnife](http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/). It will reduce boilerplate code

Comment: are you getting any error ?

Comment: @Champandorid nothing error, i want to use less coding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do it in one line!

```
context.startActivity(new Intent(context, GridView.class).putExtra("ID",Integer.valueOf(mRestaurantList.get(position).getRestaurantId())));
```

Though you need to retrieve the value in other way than bundle extra.

```
getIntent().getIntExtra("ID",0);
```